# How to stop the overdue email notification in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I received an overdue email notification but when I click the `Open this task`, the following message appears:

> An error occurred while retrieving the workflow task details. This may be caused by:
>
> - Not having connectivity to the server
> - The task no longer exists
> - You do not have permission to access the task
>
> If this error persist, contact your system administrator.**

I want to know how I can stop this notification if the workflow was eliminated or even the workflow was approved.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permission to access the task.  What is the title in the subject line of the email?  Does it reveal the name of a List or Task List?  Are there any links in the body of the email, which you could hover over?  If there is a link, it will reveal the name of the list - perhaps this could help you to track it down.  You could also just contact the SP Administrator to get them to help locate where these emails come from.  If you do not have the correct permissions, can one of your colleagues to try to access the task?  In this way you can eliminate 'permissions'.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to make sure that you know which server sends the overdue emails (this can be checked in the email header), make sure there is no other farm have the same settings with the current farm .

• Here are the steps to view the properties of the email.

1. Pop out the email in issue.
2. Click on Files.
3. On the right  hand pane you will see an option called properties.